# AsyncTasks and cancelling

Tags: android, asynchronous

My application works like a launcher, when an app is launched from within my application, a timer starts that allows you to play for only a certain amount of time. If you return to my launcher, however, I want the timer to pause and then pick up again once you launch another app. I have the following:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        while (playTime < ALLOWED_TIME) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                long endTime = System.nanoTime() / Constants.NANO_SECONDS;
                int endTimeSec = (int) endTime;
                playTime = endTimeSec - START_TIME;

                if (stored.getBoolean("Foreground", false)) {
                    break;
                    cancel(true); //run this code if Arcade app is exited before time expires
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

EDIT: See answer, as it turns out reordering an excerpt of code was necessary to properly cancel background task.

Comment: `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, error, duration) toast.show()` you are updating ui you should get an exception coz you are updating ui from background thread which is not possible

Comment: So I invoke only `cancel(true)` inside my if{} and then do all the other stuff in `onCancelled()`. The problem that seems to persist is that the if() never has a value of true, I guess proofreading some stuff is a good idea, thanks for this update though

Comment: What Raghunandran says: you can create a Toast only from the UI thread, like in onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute. There's other ways to run it on the UI thread, but from the doInBackground, it won't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the posted code, the following code snippet effectively cancels the background thread and the associated loop occurring in the background:

```
if (true) {
    cancel(true); //this code cancels the background thread, breaks the loop therein
    break;
}

protected void onCancelled(){
    //anything to be run on main thread after cancellation
}
```